# Is it just me or is there a sudden uptick in Clash of Clans questions with tons of “me too” answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

The subject says it all. I am light user of this particular Stack Exchnage site, but rolled over in the past few hours to [see lots of “Clash of Clans” posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=Clash%20of%20Clans) new and old on the main page. Including tons of “me too” like answers. What’s up?

FWIW, [this is a pretty amazing thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150359/2-clash-of-clans-account-on-the-same-game-center-account). Ditto [with this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156496/2-different-game-center-apple-ids-one-village). This many “me too” responses? Really?

Comment: See also: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/2294/9388

Comment: alas, that thread doesn't appear to be pretty amazing any more...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of thing is very common on Ask Different when a change occurs with something within the scope of the site. It begins with a reasonable question on the subject, and thanks to SE's very high SERP rank, is the #1 result for many search queries.

People then post 'me too' answers, either because they want to participate in the question so that they believe they can be updated when the question is updated (like some forums do, unaware of the 'favourite' feature), or simply because they want to express that they are experiencing the same problem.

Especially with the topic of Clash of Clans, where the stereotypical demographic of the general user base usually results with low quality posts, the situation is extenuated, but the same thing happens with other topics as well.

Downvote, comment and flag the posts. If you have >10k, protect the question to prevent further answers, and vote to delete the posts if you have >20k.

Comment: I would have through that all ridiculous "games" such as Clash of Clans would be totally off topic for SE. You have to draw a line somewhere - this is not *Yahoo Answers*.

Answer (score 6):

I've cleaned up most of them now. If you run into more, just flag them as usual.

As for the reason, I can only guess. Maybe there was a change of rules on CoC server side which triggered some changes in the app.

Comment: Fingers crossed that SuperCell finally disabled "log out log in" to switch villages on the same device, since that seems to be a large percentage of the questions we get about it normally.

Comment: All this question are from 1 score users. IS it a recent change user without achieved scores can ask or I was  just oblivious?

Comment: @iskra anybody can ask questions, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: Then I wonder why I haven't seen such a flood of low quality answers and questions before.

Comment: @iskra Different user group probably (the typical CoC gamer is  much younger than the average on the site)

Comment: It is not only about CoC. It is all over the site now. Answers that are questions, answers that are rants. Maybe I have a bit grim view but still I don't remember it was that much of them like when I was active last time i.e. about half a year ago.

Comment: The great fun about self-moderating sites is that you can go ahead and edit/downvote/flag all these things which bother you :-)

Comment: Oh just drop using the site when it will become total mess.(

Comment: Feel free to create a new question/topic here on the Meta site to discuss this in a broader audience. There may be other ways on how to handle an inflow of new, not so experienced users.

Comment: Thanks @patrix I will look into it.